# How can i change the box height in my meteor app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

In my meteor app when I click my button it makes my `div.box` modal and full-width, but not full-screen. I want the height also be full-height. 
My code looks like this:

```
'click .expand-link': function (event, template) {
         console.log('.expand-link')
         event.preventDefault();

         var button = $(event.target);
         var box = button.closest('div.box'); //        var box = $(this).closest('div.box'); //        var button = $(this).find('i');
         var content = box.find('div.box-content');

         button.toggleClass('fa-expand').toggleClass('fa-compress');
         box.toggleClass('expanded');
         $(document.body).toggleClass('body-expanded');
         var timeout = 0;
         if ($(document.body).hasClass('body-expanded')) {
             timeout = 100;
         }
         setTimeout(function () {
             box.toggleClass('expanded-padding');
         }, timeout);
         setTimeout(function () {
             box.resize();
             box.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
         }, timeout + 50);
```

I searched for CSS file but I could not find class 'expanded'. How can I change the height when it has 'expanded' class ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make class for "expanded" in the CSS ??

```
.expanded {
 height: ...;
 /* Properties ... */
}
```

Comment: I think there should already exist an "expanded" class because the code uses it. The problem is that I don't know where it is defined. Normally it should be in a CSS fie but maybe in meteor app there is something different ?

Comment: What packages are you using with metoer ?

Comment: When I have a look at under packages folder I see "orionjs_bootstrap" and "rzymek_fullcalendar" folders.

Comment: See Meteor is just a MV* framework and has no frontend so I don't belive the styles come from here. It most likely is coming from the oriomjs_bootstrap css or the fullcallender CSS.

Comment: I have found the css file. But there exists already 'height: %100' attribute. But it does not work. It looks like this; 

    .expanded {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        border: 0;
        z-index: 3000 !important;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: 0.2s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

Comment: Sorry i could not format the code and it doesn't allow me to edit anymore

Comment: Yes so just call your class last and overwrite the styles with height: 100% "!important"